# Is it possible to add \chapter after a few \part's at the same level of hierarchy?

Tags: hyperref, table-of-contents, sectioning, bookmarks

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[bookmarks, bookmarkstype=toc]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\part{First part}
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \chapter{Second chapter}

\part{Second part}
    \chapter{Third chapter}
    \chapter{Fourth chapter}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

In the resulting PDF both tables of contents (the one produced by `\tableofcontents` and the list of PDF bookmarks) have the following hierarchy:

```
Introduction
First part
- First chapter
- Second chapter
Second part
- Third chapter
- Fourth chapter
- Conclusion
```

Is it possible to put 'Conclusion' at the same level of hierarchy with 'Introduction', 'First part' and 'Second part'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to adapt only the bookmarks: Either use bookmark instead of hyperref (it will load hyperref internally)

```
\usepackage{bookmark}
...

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\chapter{conclusion}
```

Or

```
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@chapter{-1}
\makeatother
\chapter{Conclusion}
```

Comment: Thank you, both of your methods work. There is only one issue: no empty line between 'Fourth chapter' and 'Conclusion' in ToC (to visually separate them), which I fixed by adding ``\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{\baselineskip}\protect}`` before ``\chapter{conclusion}``.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the comment by @fjarri, in my case it was `\cftbeforepartskip` rather than `\baselineskip`.

Comment: In my case (the `book` document class), for some reason, the `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` trick given in previous comments adds space *after* the next `\chapter`! So that I get the wanted result by putting the command before the chapter that precedes the conclusion…

Answer (score 4):

```
\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Conclusion}
```

And remember to do the same for the introduction if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a "Conclusion" that is at the same level of hierarchy as your "First part" and your "Second part", then I suggest to use `\part*{Conclusion}`.

Comment: ``\part*`` does not put the part in the ToC; and, moreover, I'd prefer a chapter, not a part.

Comment: @Bogdan: You can combine `\part*{Conclusion}` and (from @Herbert's answer) `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Conclusion}`. If you prefer `\chapter`, see @Ulrike's answer.